# Turning a unicode code point into a unicode character in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I'm parsing hex/unicode escapes from text.

So I'll have an input string like

```
\x{abcd}
```

which is easy enough - I wind up with an array `["ab", "cd"]` which I call `digits` and do this to it:

```
return bytes(int(d, 16) for d in digits).decode("utf-8")
```

So I basically accept everything between the `{}` as a UTF-8-encoded character and turn it into a character. Simple.

```
>>> bytes(int(d, 16) for d in ["e1", "88", "92"]).decode("utf-8")
'ሒ'
```

But I want to go the other way: `\u{1212}` should result in the same character. The problem is, I don't know how to treat the resulting `["12", "12"]` as a unicode code point instead of UTF-8 bytes to get the ሒ character again.

How can I do this in python 3?

Comment: For the UTF-8 case, consider `codecs.decode("e18892", 'hex_codec').decode('utf-8')` or `binascii.unhexlify("e18892").decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: That should cut down some code, thanks. `unhexlify` is a hilarious name for that function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chr` after parsing the number as base-16:

```
>>> chr(int('1212', 16))
'ሒ'
>>> '\u1212'
'ሒ'
```

If you're replacing this globally in some string, using `re.sub` with a substitution function could make this simple:

```
import re

def replacer(match):
    if match.group(2) == 'u':
        return chr(int(match.group(3), 16))
    elif match.group(2) == 'x':
        return  # ...

re.sub(r'(\\(x|u)\{(.*?)\})', replacer, r'\x{abcd} foo \u{1212}')
```

Comment: That was so simple it's embarrassing haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

do you mean to encode the string like this?

```
>>> print u"\u1212"
ሒ
>>> print u"\u00A9"
©
```

edit:

if you start with a string, it's just

```
>>> chr(int("1212", 16))
'ሒ'
```

Comment: I'm parsing user text at runtime so I don't think I can use `\uxxxx` - I suppose I could create a python string literal and `eval()` it, though I'd prefer not to if possible.